# How import from webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I built my es6 code by webpack, but I can't import from this built file. I get "undefined"

This is my src code:

```
export const debugFunc = () => { 
  console.log('debug') 
}
```

And there is I try to use it:

```
import { debugFunc } from './debugFunc'
```

my webpack config is very simple

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/lib",
    filename: "main.js",
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you import the file?

Comment: There is no need to require webpack in this webpack.config.js

Comment: For writing libraries I recommend using rollup. Have a look at [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-lib)
Webpack is a bundler and thus not designed to output code that will be consumed by other developers or your self.